# create Texture with ONE channel in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

in an iOS app i want to put a texture on an object, render the scene, read it back and then read the "color" of that object to identify it.

This works fine, i use an RGB texture for that.  The data to create the texture from are then:
1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0.

This takes quite a large amount of RAM, wasting 66%.  I would like to use a texture with just ONE channel.

Reading the OpenGL specs for glTexImage2D it looks to me that using the format GL_RED is the way to go, but it does not seem to be available in iOS.

Can anybody confirm that or tell me another way on how to create a texture with just ONE channel in iOS?

Thanks for any hints,
Torsten.

Comment: If each object only has one color, couldn't you just use a tiny texture and have GL stretch it to fit? Or even send the color to the shader directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most recent iOS devices (> iOS 5.0) should support [`EXT_texture_rg`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_rg.txt), which allows the creation of one-channel and two-channel renderbuffers (and textures) using the `GL_RED_EXT` and `GL_RG_EXT` texture format enums. However, you should query for the presence of the extension by calling `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` and checking the returned value for `GL_EXT_texture_rg`).